# Opening swf in flash player from javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash

I have a project developed with flex, in which reports are generated as SWF files. My requirement is that when I click an html button on my page, that SWF file should be opened with flash player installed within my system. How can I achieve the same if I want to do with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you link directly to the SWF file the browser will attempt to open it. In order to be able to choose if you want to save/open the file in external application you need to alter the HTTP headers - which means some serverside scripting